# Multiple targets for each application

Tags: cmake

I'm new to cmake and I want to achieve the following behavior. I have a subdirectory `programs` containing multiple independent programs. For each program, I want to add different targets (e.g. analyze or test) named with a prefix.
This should allow me to execute them like `make prog1-analyze` or `make prog2-test`.

Furthermore, I want to also execute all targets of the same type (e.g. the `test` target) at once (e.g. via `make test`).

To do so, I have the following directory structure with two `CMakeLists.txt` files.

```
CMakeLists.txt
programs
  |-- prog1.c
  |-- prog2.c
  |-- CMakeLists.txt
```

The top-level file contains a macro definition `add_application`, whereas the `programs/CMakeLists.txt` invokes this macro for each program. But how to write the macro such that I have multiple targets and a global target for all targets of the same type?

```
macro(add_application NAME SOURCE_FILES)
endmacro()
```

Comment: Not quite the answer you are looking for, but you should *really* take a look at the `add_test()` command, and `ctest`. Also, from an architectural standpoint, you shouldn't test executables. Those `prog1.c` and `prog2.c` should be thin wrappers for functions implemented in a library. (Parsing command line options, setting up required parameters, call library function.) Library functions can easily be tested by a dedicated *test* executable. (Which, you guessed it, you'd add with `add_test()` and can run through `ctest`.)

Answer (score 0):

In `add_application()` macro body you may add **per-application targets** as usual, constructing their names with use of macro parameter *NAME*.

As for **global target**, you may create it once outside of the macro. Inside macro body you may just call `add_dependencies()` for make the *global* target dependent from *per-application* one:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_custom_target(analize) # Create global target

macro(add_application NAME SOURCE_FILES)
    ... # Create application target itself
    add_custom_target(${NAME}-analize ...) # Create per-application target
    add_dependencies(analize ${NAME}-analize) # Dependency between global and per-application targets.
endmacro()
```

---

Example uses "analize" target because "test" target is *reserved* by CTest. It is better to not use it for other purposes.